# change interpreter python path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

i want to change the following path in the terminal from

```
PS C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
```

to

```
PS C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
```

This python version is used:
[python_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3cHY.png)

I tried the following things:

- set the environment variable path python310 to the top
- delete the enviroment variable path python39
- add an interpreter path manually by clicking on the python version in the picture
- change the path in the file "settings.json" to python310

I also restarted my comuputer but nothing works. Has anyone an idea to make this change happen. When i want to install something for python 3.10 everything is installed in the path from python 3.9.

Comment: Please don't post images or links of images of simple text.  Paste the text.

Comment: `py -3.10 -m pip install <package>`.  Make sure to run the version of python that you want to install packages into.  No need to mess with the environment.  `py` is the Python Launcher and is installed by default to manage Python versions on Windows.  `py -0` will list the installed Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the path to the python.exe file for the version where the package needs to be installed. For example:

```
C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python.exe -m pip install <package>
```

Please replace the above path with the correct one from your file system.

Comment: but how can i change this path from `PS C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages` to `PS C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages`?